# How Do We Escalate a Conflict in Editing a Question?

Tags: support

I recently posted a question about the relationship between non-semantic and non-syntactic aspects of language, and logical functionality. An SE user proposed a number of grammatical and similar edits, at first entirely within reason, but after I provided an explanation for why the proposed edits were actually not justified, this user still went ahead and edited my post, as if they didn't pay any attention to my explanation at all. Moreover, this user is not even a moderator or significant contributor to the PhilosophySE in particular.

How can we ward off this kind of "outside interference"?

Comment: Edited the title for specificty and created a tag 'conflict-resolution'. This seems to be an integral issue in the operation of this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two steps of "escalation":

1. It is your post and you have every right to do a rollback and make the edits undone.
2. If your post is re-edited in a way you consider inappropriate, raise a flag and ask for the post to be locked for edits - temporarily or permanently. That way, there is no way to edit the post against your intentions and without your approval.

Comment: How do we do a rollback?